# ng-switch-when - does not clear the selection

Tags: angularjs

issue: `ng-switch-when` does not remove the previous data when switching using the options
I have put together the sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/98q775jL/3/

select "Cash" and enter some number then
select "Check" and enter some number and if you go back to Cash you will still see the previous numbers.

my question is: how can I clear the selection once the user choose the different option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have two different values in your model. One for the cheque and one for the cash. Is that what you want? If you just want to use the ng-when to switch the label then you can take the input out of the switch and just have the one value in the model.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-switch="payment.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="Cash">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Cash :</label>

    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="Check">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Check #:</label>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.amount_tendered" />
</div>
```

So the value payment.amount_tendered is the only value that you end up with. Otherwise, if both values are needed then you may have to write a function that clears the value for you and bind it to the change event of the select.

Comment: in this particular case I would need to have two separate inputs and writing a change event to clear the selection?

Comment: is that only option for me to have another change event?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it may be the quickest based on the code you have. For example, try this: `<select name="type" ng-model="payment.type" ng-dropdown required ng-change="payment.check = ''">`. Now every time the selection changes the payment.check value is blank. Can you expand on that?

Comment: I have updated jsfiddle please have a look at it and does not seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/98q775jL/9/

Comment: statements in javascript are separated by ; not ,. Replace your , with ;

Comment: I see in jsfiddle working but when I do the same in my code it's not working so frustrated arggg... Can you replace the entire logic with something Ng-change and have function in controller that displays based on the selection ?

Comment: Yes. That would be best. Add a function in controller that clears the fields and call it with ng-change of the select.